# Ignoring the problematic files in the Stanford NLP command that works with file list

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford Cornelp to get parse tree for a large number of texts. I am processing a list of files by invoking a single JVM by using the command-

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP [ -props myprops.props ] -filelist filelist.txt
```

However, I'm facing one problem with this approach. Some of the texts in my batch are may be too long or complex, hence the program is running out of memory and getting terminated. Also, the error it returns doesn't contain the name of textfile it got crashed on.

But what I would like the program to do is to just ignore the file where it faces error and continue to the next file in the file list. (One option for me would be to invoke a java command separately for each file, but that makes the whole process almost exponentially slower). Is it possible to do using the "filelist" command?

Answer (score 1):

If you add `-parse.maxlen 100` you can tell the parser to only parse on sentences of token length 100 or less.  You can fine-tune the limit you want for your purposes.